# Sentence patterns SVOA vs SVOC

Tags: sentence-construction

1. I saw a girl **in the garden**.
2. I placed the camera **on the tripod**.

My intuition is that in the first sentence, the prepositional phrase is an object complement, and the sentence pattern is SVOC.

In the second sentence, the prepositional phrase is an adverbial, and the sentence pattern is SVOA.

But, if someone asks where did you see the girl and where did you place the camera, the answers are *in the garden* and *on the tripod* respectively.

Then, can't they both be adverbials too? Or, are they already adverbials?

Comment: I'm not sure what you understand by "object complement", but the syntax of your first example is inherently ambiguous. The words **in the garden** could be understood as "adjectivally" applying to either of two relevant nouns - the object *(**a girl**)* or the subject *(**I**)* - OR adverbially modifying the verb *(**saw**)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica , I understand the object complement as words/phrases describing, identifying or locating the object in a sentence. And an *adverb/adverbial* as completing the meaning of a verb indicating when, where, how, etc. an action is done.